# Apply singleton template to class with parameterized constructor

Tags: c++, class, parameters, singleton

I have a class (Test) that I want to turn into a singleton.  I'm thinking of declaring the Test class to descend from a singleton template class that I will reuse:

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
    public:
        static T& getInstance()
        {
            static T instance;
            return instance;
        }
    protected:
        Singleton() {}
        ~Singleton() {}
    public:
        Singleton(Singleton const &) = delete;
        Singleton& operator=(Singleton const &) = delete;
};
```

How can I use this template (generically) to turn a class into into a singleton if the constructor needs a parameter?  For example Test might be:

```
class Test {
  public:
    Test(int A);
}
```

Is there a way to generically use the above template to turn Test into a singleton?  (Obviously the first call to instance will use the parameters, and subsequent calls to instance will have the parameters ignored)

Comment: Maybe passing the parameter with `getInstance()`? First call would win. Generally the _Singleton Pattern_ doesn't seems to be the best approach for the problem you want to solve.

Comment: "I have a class (Test) that I want to turn into a singleton" - sounds like a bad idea. Singletons (and other types of global variables) usually lead to a ton of pain once a project grows. Tight coupling. Creation/destruction before/after main. The [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). And more. I would stay away from the singleton *anti*-pattern. Have been bitten before; it's not fun. And getting rid of them once you realise how bad they are, can be a challenge.

Comment: The problem with this is the singleton is created only **once** but the creator function is called every time you want a reference to that **one** singleton. How will you pass a parameter only once and never again to that function?

Comment: Or do you want a different *singleton* for every parameter value?

Comment: Think about using a pure virtual interface and [_Factory design pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns) to create your instances. Implementing factories as final singeletons is usually fine, from the design point of view.

Comment: OK - I'm convinced singleton with parameters isn't right solution.  I'll still explore singleton for learning - interesting.